# CLOB to String conversion + java 1.8

Tags: java

The below program is always giving the exception

> "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection"  in this line of " final Reader reader = clb.getCharacterStream();"

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ClobStringConversion {

    public static String clobStringConversion(Clob clb) throws IOException, SQLException
    {
        if (clb == null)
              return  "";

               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
               String strng;

               try{
                   final Reader reader = clb.getCharacterStream();
                   final BufferedReader br     = new BufferedReader(reader);

                   int b;
                   while(-1 != (b = br.read()))
                   {
                       sb.append((char)b);
                   }
                   br.close();
               }

               catch (SQLException e)
               {
                   //log.error("SQL. Could not convert CLOB to string",e);
                   return e.toString();
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   //log.error("IO. Could not convert CLOB to string",e);
                   return e.toString();
               }
               return sb.toString();
    }     

}
```

Comment: You should provide more details like the database, JDBC driver that you're using, what is the expected length of CLOB, whether this is happening intermittently or every time.

Comment: Currently using Oracle database with jdbc driver . CLOB length is very big.

Comment: Going to need to provide more code if you expect help here. This error message is stating that by this time, the socket connection has already been closed; you can not read data from a closed stream. Nothing we can do here.

Comment: Please confirm if it happens every time you try to read it or just some times. When it happens is the JDBC connection closed out, meaning can you run other queries at the time and just cannot read the CLOB data. If you can not run other queries then it means that JDBC connection has closed as suggested by @MattClark . You will have to increase the timeout duration of the database in that case.

Comment: It is happened every time.Currently using spring boot application and not sure where need to increase the duration of database connection. I am getting list of object from the database then am looping the list and converting the particular variable which has return type is clob.

Comment: Please indent your code properly and use curly braces around conditional and loop bodies.

Comment: Here is a code-style hint for you: If you are using Java 7+, you can use the try-with-resources statement, that will ensure you, that all closables will be closed, regardless of the occurrence of an exception: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

So instead of `try{
   Reader reader = clb.getCharacterStream();
   BufferedReader br     = new BufferedReader(reader);`
you would write `try (Reader reader = clb.getCharacterStream();
   BufferedReader br     = new BufferedReader(reader); ) {`

Both readers will be closed after reaching block-end

Comment: I used "getClobAsString" in rowMapper and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably closing the connection before calling `clobStringConversion()`. Try closing the connection after reading the Clob.